# How to align perfectly the logo and the navbar and the logo

Tags: html, css, sass, styles, haml

after make many researches, I didn't figure out how I could align the logo of my web application and the nav items. I created a logo image, but I can't align it the right way!
Hopefully some of you could help me out.

Here are the Haml code

```
  %header
     .header_inner
     = link_to image_tag('loo.png'), root_path, id: "logo"
     %nav
        - if user_signed_in?
           = link_to "New Note", new_note_path
           = link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete 
       - else
           = link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path
```

Here the Sass code

```
header {
background: $dark_gray;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
padding: 1.75rem 0;
border-bottom: 7px solid $green;
.header_inner {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    #logo {
        float: left;
        padding: 1px 0;
    }
    nav {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 10px;
        float: left;
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.1rem;
            line-height: 1.5;
            margin-left: 1rem;
            &:hover {
                color: $green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the result of the navbar styling
[Navbar Styling Result - Application Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hu30.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B'coz of you have give some css like: `float:left, margin-left:1rem` etc..etc.

Do something

```
float:none
margin:0 auto;
display:inline-block;
width:100%
```

hope this help...